# open EDF file in python

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

I am usin mac and I tried to open an edf file in python using pyEDFlib .

```
import pyedflib
import numpy as np
file_name='test.edf'
f = pyedflib.EdfReader(file_name)
```

but I got the follwoing error .

```
  File "/Users/liat/Dropbox/Penn/PrepEDF.py", line 4, in <module>
    f = pyedflib.EdfReader(file_name)
  File "pyedflib/_extensions/_pyedflib.pyx", line 114, in pyedflib._extensions._pyedflib.CyEdfReader.__init__
  File "pyedflib/_extensions/_pyedflib.pyx", line 152, in pyedflib._extensions._pyedflib.CyEdfReader.open
  File "pyedflib/_extensions/_pyedflib.pyx", line 124, in pyedflib._extensions._pyedflib.CyEdfReader.check_open_ok
IOError: the file is not EDF(+) or BDF(+) compliant (startdate)
```

The thing is that when I tried to open it with matlab using edfread.m it menaged to open it (as a matrix). I am trying to move to python so I'd appriciate an explanation how to open edfs in python.
thank you .

Comment: try reading one of these [samples](https://www.teuniz.net/edf_bdf_testfiles/)

Comment: tried and it opened it successfully.

Comment: then i would suggest that there is something genuinely wrong with you edf file. you could try opening it in a [browser](https://www.teuniz.net/edfbrowser/) and this may give you some more information as to what is wrong with it

Comment: the thing is the Matlab manages to open it.

Comment: matlab is its own beast.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem exactly.
for example for all EDF file in [physionet dataset](https://archive.physionet.org/pn4/eegmmidb/)(eegmmidb)
After some days research finally I've understood that you **MUST** install pyEDFlib version of **0.1.17** in python:

```
pip install pyEDFlib==0.1.17
```

or for google colab:

```
!pip install pyEDFlib==0.1.17
```

Now, it's work for me successfully.